# FSharp.Data -- How to Handle Null JSON Values?

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

I'm trying to convert the FSharp.Data examples to solutions for my problem i'm dealing with, but i'm just not getting very far.

#### Problem

Given an endpoint that returns json similar to:

```
{
  Products:[{
    Id:43,
    Name:"hi"
  },
  {
    Id:45,
    Name:"other prod"
  }
  ]
}
```

How can i load the data and then only get the `Id`s out of real, existing data?

I dont understand how to "pattern match out" the possibilities that:

- it could return nothing
- that `root.Products` could be not existing/empty
- that `Id` might not exist

#### Attempt Via Null Matching

```
namespace Printio

open System 
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

module PrintioApi =
    type ApiProducts = JsonProvider<"https://api.print.io/api/v/1/source/widget/products?recipeId=f255af6f-9614-4fe2-aa8b-1b77b936d9d6&countryCode=US">

let getProductIds url =
    async {
        let! json = ApiProducts.AsyncLoad url
        let ids = match json with
            | null  -> [||]
            | _ -> 
                match json.Products with
                    | null -> [||]
                    | _ -> Array.map (fun (x:ApiProducts.Product)-> x.Id) json.Products

        return ids
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need pattern matching for checking whether it's an empty array of not if you have some level of confidence in the source data. Something like this might just work fine: -

```
let getProductIds url =
    async {
        let! json = ApiProducts.AsyncLoad url
        return json.Products |> Seq.map(fun p -> p.Id) |> Seq.cache
    }
```

Note you shouldn't use Async.RunSynchronously when in an async { } block - you can do a let! binding which will await the result asynchronously.

Comment: what is the `Seq.cache` for? I looked it up on MSDN but is there a specific reason for using it with the JsonTypeProvider?

Comment: Nope. Its simply that sequences are lazily-evaluated so if you used that sequence many times the map function would get called for each of them (as would .Select() with Linq in C#). Seq.cache guarantees that it will only get enumerated once. You could achieve a similar effect with Seq.toList or Seq.toArray.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** When I wrote this answer, I didn't fully understand the capabilities of the JSON type provider. It turns out that you can populate it with a list of sample JSON documents, which enables you to handle all sorts of scenarios where data may or may not be present. I use it quite a lot these days, so I no longer believe in what I originally wrote. I'll leave the original answer here, in case anyone can derive any value from it.

See my [other answer here on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39755506/126014) for a demonstration of how I'd do it today.

---

While type providers are nice, I believe that it's conceptually wrong to attempt to treat something like JSON, which has no schema, and no type safety, as strongly typed data. Instead of using type providers, I use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), and [FSharp.Interop.Dynamic](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic) to write queries like this:

```
let response = client.GetAsync("").Result
let json = response.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync().Result
let links = json?links :> obj seq
let address =
    links
    |> Seq.filter (fun l -> l?rel <> null && l?href <> null)
    |> Seq.filter (fun l -> l?rel.ToString() = rel)
    |> Seq.map (fun l -> Uri(l?href.ToString()))
    |> Seq.exactlyOne
```

where `client` is an instance of `HttpClient`, and `ReadAsJsonAsync` is a little helper method defined like this:

```
type HttpContent with
    member this.ReadAsJsonAsync() =
        let readJson (t : Task<string>) =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject t.Result
        this.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(fun t -> readJson t)
```

Comment: Hmmmm not sure about your point of there not being a schema. Yes the schema might not be enforced by JSON, but there's more often than not a schema nonetheless. Same as CSV. Same as Mongo DB. Etc etc.

Comment: The service serving up the data may or may not have an underlying schema, but that's irrelevant from the client's perspective. Auto-generating .NET types based on sample data doesn't protect you, as a client developer, from changes in the service's schema. When you write distributed software, it would be advisable to follow [Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle); generating types based on a snapshot of sample data isn't particularly robust.

Comment: And yet people are happily using JSON and inferred schemas over, say, XML and XSD - indeed, much more happily IMHO.

Comment: It depends on the intended use case. These type providers and their inference algorithms were designed thinking about exploratory programming, so they don't provide you any type safety guarantee. In practice though, in many cases the xml, json, or csv are actually regular enough that it is safe to use the TPs

Comment: @MarkSeemann There exists a JSON Schema proposal (now Draft4 in IETF).http://json-schema.org/ I think this would make much more interesting the Type provider option.

Comment: @MarkSeemann hi mark, would you still architect a strictly layered model in F#, i.e. would you have ApiModel types that your controllers expose, and e.g. Dto types that are used for any backing stores (including other HTTP APIs) and repositories/domain models that map?

Comment: @devdigital This is what I tend to do these days: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2016/03/18/functional-architecture-is-ports-and-adapters

Answer (score 2):

Give the type provider enough examples to infer those cases. Example:

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = """
{
  Products:[{
    Id:null,
    Name:"hi"
  },
  {
    Id:45,
    Name:"other prod"
  }
  ]
}
"""

type MyJsonType = JsonProvider<sample>
```

But do note it will never be 100% safe if the json is not regular enough

Answer (score 2):

If you suspect that your data source may contain some missing values, you can set `SampleIsList = true` in the JsonProvider, and give it a list of samples, instead of a single example:

```
open FSharp.Data

type ApiProducts = JsonProvider<"""
[
    {
        "Products": [{
            "Id": 43,
            "Name": "hi"
        }, {
            "Name": "other prod"
        }]
    },
    {}
]
""", SampleIsList = true>
```

As Gustavo Guerra also hints in his answer, `Products` is already a list, so you can supply one example of a product that has an `Id` (the first one), and one example that doesn't have an `Id` (the second one).

Likewise, you can give an example where `Products` is entirely missing. Since the root object contains no other data, this is simply the empty object: `{}`.

The `JsonProvider` is intelligent enough to interpret a missing `Products` property as an empty array.

Since a product may or may not have an `Id`, this property is inferred to have the type `int option`.

You can now write a function that takes a JSON string as input and gives you all the IDs it can find:

```
let getProductIds json =
    let root = ApiProducts.Parse json
    root.Products |> Array.choose (fun p -> p.Id)
```

Notice that it uses `Array.choose` instead of `Array.map`, since `Array.choose` automatically chooses only those `Id` values that are `Some`.

You can now test with various values to see that it works:

```
> getProductIds """{ "Products": [{ "Id": 43, "Name": "hi" }, { "Id": 45, "Name": "other prod"  }] }""";;
> val it : int [] = [|43; 45|]

> getProductIds """{ "Products": [{ "Id": 43, "Name": "hi" }, { "Name": "other prod" }] }""";;
> val it : int [] = [|43|]

> getProductIds "{}";;
> val it : int [] = [||]
```

It still crashes on empty input, though; if there's a `TryParse` function or similar for `JsonProvider`, I haven't found it yet...